# Where do I set the HTML that wraps a module's config $form inputs?

Tags: 7, theming, configuration

I am transferring a module from one site to another. All is well except the modules form (where I set settings, upload images, etc). On the original site this is nicely wrapped in a table with each section being a row, but on my new site the form elements are just placed in one after the other, appearing vertically. This is despite me copying the modules .inc, .tpl and .module files almost verbatim.

I'm new to Drupal in general so am struggling with this a bit. Would anyone know where this is set (what file, what function)?

```
function gallery_grid_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();

  $items['gallery_grid'] = array(
    'render element' => 'element',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_grid') . '/plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/templates',
    'template' => 'gallery-grid',
    'variables' => [],
  );

  // Draggable table for gallery-grid admin form.
  $items['gallery_grid_draggable_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'fieldset',
    'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_grid') . '/plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/gallery_grid.theme.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Contents of gallery_grid.theme.inc:

```
function theme_gallery_grid_draggable_form($variables) {
  $fieldset = $variables['fieldset'];
  $rows = array();

  // Table for the items.
  foreach (element_children($fieldset) as $key) {
    $fieldset[$key]['weight']['#attributes']['class'] = array('item-weight');
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        render($fieldset[$key]['image_file']),
        render($fieldset[$key]['image_url']) . render($fieldset[$key]['image_title']),
        render($fieldset[$key]['delete_row']),
        render($fieldset[$key]['weight']),
      ),
      'class' => array('draggable'),
    );
  }

  // Header and render.
  $header = array(t('Image *'), t('Image Settings'), t('Actions'), t('Weight'));
  $table_id = 'items-table';
  $output = theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows' => $rows,
    'attributes' => array('id' => $table_id),
    'sticky' => FALSE,
  ));

  // Add tabledrag.
  drupal_add_tabledrag($table_id, 'order', 'sibling', 'item-weight');
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Look in the module for hook_theme(), and add it to your original post. That can likely give us an indication of what's missing.

Comment: @Jaypan Hi Jaypan, have added it above. The 'Draggable table' is what's been copied from the original module

Comment: Did you also copy this file: `drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_grid') . 'plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/gallery_grid.theme.inc'`?

Comment: @Jaypan yes I did. I've added the contents of that file above. Note I thought it was strange that the fucntion started with `theme_` so tried removing it to no affect.

Comment: What file did you add the contents to? And the function name should be prefixed with `theme_`, so you shouldn't remove that.

Comment: The admin theme may have also implemented form templates and preprocess functions to customize the theme hook above.

Comment: Is that file at the path `drupal_get_path('module', 'gallery_grid') . 'plugins/content_types/gallery_grid/gallery_grid.theme.inc`?

Comment: @Jaypan, yes that's file

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at form templates? The steps change a little if you are using a starter theme, but the basics are the same.

http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/forms/with-templates